# Accessing database from a different application

Tags: android, android-sqlite

How can i access a database which is in a different application. I want to access the data and use it for an other application how am i suppose to do it. I dont even have a clue how to access data from a different application please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this article](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

"Application modularity – The Android system allows applications that are signed by the same certificate to run in the same process, if the applications so requests, so that the system treats them as a single application. In this way you can deploy your application in modules, and users can update each of the modules independently if needed."

"Code/data sharing through permissions – The Android system provides signature-based permissions enforcement, so that an application can expose functionality to another application that is signed with a specified certificate. By signing multiple applications with the same certificate and using signature-based permissions checks, your applications can share code and data in a secure manner. "

Answer (score 0):

please use content provider for accomplishing the same

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about **[content provider?](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)**, you can implement the above functionality by using this.

**For example,** Calendar, Contacts are doing the same.

Check:

1. [Creating a Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html)
2. [Android SQLite Database and ContentProvider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

in Android diff app can share the data with help of content provider 
below will help you

http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/content-provider-example-1.html

Stay smiling